# How to format date column in jquery data table

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, datatables

Am using jquery datatable to displaying the values from the database. It displaying the date values in yyyy-mm-dd H:i:s format. I want to display it as dd-mm-yyyy H:i:s format. how to do that,  the function script is given below.

```
$(function () {
    $('#dTable').DataTable({
        'paging'      : true,
        'lengthChange': true,
        'searching'   : true,
        'ordering'    : true,
        'info'        : true,
        'autoWidth'   : false,
        'pageLength'  : 50,


        'lengthMenu'  : [[10, 25, 50,100,500, -1], [10, 25, 50,100,500, "All"]],
        'aaSorting'   : [[9, 'asc']],

        'aoColumns': [{"bSortable": false},null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,{"bSortable": true},{"bSortable": false}],
        'fnRowCallback': function(nRow, aData, iDisplayIndex, iDisplayIndexFull) 
        });
    }
```

Comment: where is your date? in this where is your columns?

Comment: @DilipHirapara  not added in this, this is just table function. I have column in php page

Comment: So do you want to change the date format from php side? if yes add your php code

Comment: I want to change the date format from javascript side. Not in php side

Answer (score 0):

You can use the momentjs. I am attaching the reference link for you.
https://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/

Answer (score 0):

Check out: [Date-fns](https://date-fns.org/v2.7.0/docs/format) which is a lighter alternative to **Moment.js**

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use the fnRowCallback like this:

```
function(nRow, aData, iDisplayIndex, iDisplayIndexFull) {
    let date = new Date(aData.your_date);
    let newDate = date.toString('dd-MM-yyyy'); //your format
    return newDate;
}
```

if the date isn't in all rows you should conditionals to rule the rows in and out.